# Working with Modules phpBrowser and webDriver together

Tags: php, testing, codeception

As you know, phpBrowser is faster than webDriver. What should I do if it's only necessary to perform some acceptance tests in webDriver, and I can do the rest in phpBrowser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one additional test suite for acceptance testing.
One should be configured to use PhpBrowser module, second - WebDriver.